# Reading an specific key from JSON using Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, casting, mean-stack

I am new to all JavaScript and angular. so I am struggling to do the following:
I have the following service, to read X from a local JSON file. The X is what user select from a dropdownbox:

```html
   getBySector(sector){

    this.http.get('../../assets/Sectors.json').map(res => res).subscribe
    (res => {
        this.SectorsArray = res as ISectors[]; 

        this.SectorsArray= res.find(item=>item.Sector===sector);

         console.log(this.industrySectorsArray);
         return this.industrySectorsArray;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    )
  }
```

as an additional note, I have an interface which is ISector and matches the JSOn file.

The above code give me in Console the exact thing I expect. which is the following:

```js
{IndustrySector: "Households", isSelected: "false", dataSubjectCategories: Array(2), dataTypeCategories: "Data", SubIndustries: Array(2)}
```

HOW can I return the above object/json output to ms TS file where I have called the service? 
I have done the followings which are failed:

```html
 //even this failed:
 console.log(this.readjsonService.getBySector(mission));
 
 //
 var output:Isector;
 output=this.readjsonService.getBySector(mission)
 
 // cannot subscribe to it as well
```

BTW, the find gives me  the following error: 
 error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Object'.

UPDATE:

I solved the issue the code had with the help of people who replied. But the code got another error, although it works fine. t says:

"Cannot read property 'dataSubjectCategories' of undefined"

dataSubjectCategories is one of the key in the ISector: here is the ISector:

```html
export interface ISectors {
  IndustrySector: string;
  isSelected: string;
  dataSubjectCategories:string[];
  dataTypeCategories:string[];
  SubIndustries:[{
    IndustrySector: string;
    isSelected: string;
    dataSubjectCategories:string[];
    dataTypeCategories:string[];
    SubIndustries:[{}]
  }]
}
```

Please help to resolve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: the version is 6.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, your service should just be returning the Observable and should *not* include the subscribe. Best practice suggests that you subscribe as close to the UI as possible.

My service methods look like this:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct | undefined> {
    return this.getProducts().pipe(
      map((products: IProduct[]) => products.find(p => p.productId === id))
    );
  }
```

Using the generic parameter on the get: `get<IProduct[]>` helps Angular automatically map the returned response to an array of data, ISectors in your example.

The calling code in the component then looks like this:

```
  getProduct(id: number) {
    this.productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(
      product => this.product = product,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Notice that here is where we subscribe. It then gets the product in the first function passed to the subscribe method.

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Final

Comment: Thank you. I get this error:  'Observable<ISectors>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ISectors[]>'.
  Type 'ISectors' is not assignable to type 'ISectors[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'ISectors'.

Comment: getProducts(): Observable<ISectors[]> {
    return this.http.get<ISectors[]>(this.industrySectorsURL).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getBySector(sector): Observable<ISectors[]| undefined> {
    return this.getProducts().pipe(
      map((products: ISectors[]) => products.find(p => p.sectors === sector))
    );
  }

Comment: Code is just about impossible to read in comments. Please update the question instead where the code can be formatted. Or better yet, use stackblitz to create an example.

Comment: And from what I can try to see ... looks like this one: `getBySector(sector): Observable<ISectors[]| undefined>` should *NOT* have the `[]`. In the `getBySelector` you only want to return one ... not the array.

Comment: yes true! It was a better idea to update the question. 
thanks your replied made it work. but now I have another question. please see the updated question.

Comment: Could you please explian me what the " | undefined" does?

Comment: It is a union. It basically means that the type is `ISectors` OR `undefined`. This is useful when using the find as the find will return undefined if it can't find it.

Comment: thanks @Deborah. can you please answer to the question I post in the updated question?

Comment: Since that is a different question and may require looking at more/different code ... consider reposting as a new question.